# How can I get the font(isBold,isUnderline) of a specific character in jTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I used

```
doc.setCharacterAttributes(textPane.getSelectionStart(),
           textPane.getSelectionEnd()-textPane.getSelectionStart(),red, false);
```

to change the display style of text in JTextpane.
I tried to use the function `getCharacterAttributes()`
to see what is the style of the specific text but `DefaultStyledModel` has no such method.
What can I do with this?

Extra favor:

I know in vb.net, a richtextbox has a attribute called "rtftext" or whatever, which contains the text and the font information in the richtextbox. What is the similar method/attribute in Java `JTextPane`? I tried `getDocument()` and `setDocument` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GET the attribute

You might be able to use [StyledDocument#getCharacterElement(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#getCharacterElement-int-) and [Element#getAttributes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Element.html#getAttributes--)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class CharacterAttributesTest {
  public Component makeUI() {
    StyleContext style = new StyleContext();
    StyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(style);
    try {
      doc.insertString(0, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", null);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MutableAttributeSet attr1 = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    attr1.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, Boolean.TRUE);
    attr1.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(5, 8, attr1, false);

    MutableAttributeSet attr2 = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    attr2.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Underline, Boolean.TRUE);
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(3, 20, attr2, false);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(doc);
    textPane.addCaretListener(e -> {
      if (e.getDot() == e.getMark()) {
        AttributeSet a = doc.getCharacterElement(e.getDot()).getAttributes();
        System.out.println("isBold: " + StyleConstants.isBold(a));
        System.out.println("isUnderline: " + StyleConstants.isUnderline(a));
        System.out.println("Font: " + style.getFont(a));
        System.out.println("Foreground: " + StyleConstants.getForeground(a));
      }
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(textPane));
    return p;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new CharacterAttributesTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: hi dude, thank you for sharing. Can you tell me how can I get the foreGround color by this method? It doesn't have the StyleConstants.getForeGround(a) method

Comment: May be this one: [StyleConstants#getForeground(AttributeSet)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html#getForeground-javax.swing.text.AttributeSet-)

Comment: hi, does this work:`a.getAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground)==Color.red`?

Comment: `StyleConstants.getForeground(attr) == Color.RED`

Comment: thanks dude. That guy already has my acceptance, but somehow i like ur answer better. i ll give u the acceptance instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the text to HTML? I believe the JTextPane supports HTML, so try setting your text to something like:

```
myTextPane.setText("<html>This text box has <b>bold text</b> in it!</html>");
```

OR

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class SimpleAttributeBoldItalic {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Attributes");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet attributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    attributes.addAttribute(StyleConstants.CharacterConstants.Bold, Boolean.TRUE);
    attributes.addAttribute(StyleConstants.CharacterConstants.Italic, Boolean.TRUE);

    try {
      document.insertString(document.getLength(), "Bold, Italic", attributes);
    } catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) {
      System.err.println("Bad insert");
    }

     JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(document);
    textPane.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);

    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

OR

```
Font boldFont=new Font(textArea.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, textArea.getFont().getSize());
      textArea.setFont(boldFont); // bold text
```

OR

Since you are using JTextPane, you should use SimpleAttributeSet:

```
SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setUnderline(attributeSet, true);
jta.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(0, jta.getText().length(),
    attributeSet, false);
```

Thats it.

Comment: Hi, pal, thanks for answering. But my question was to GET the attribute, not SETting. Your answer was for changing the style.

Comment: I already knew how to change the font of the characters in jTextPane, but I need to store the data(text and font), so it is very important to know which character has what font. I want to use a loop to go through every character in the jTextPane and use the if-statement to see if they are bold/italic/underline. Does these make sense to you? Thank you pal

Comment: @teslawu , another answer has posted please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the style from the selected text in JTextpane.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

 public class TesxtPane {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JFrame frame = new TextStyleTestFrame();
            frame.setSize(300, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }
}
class TextStyleTestFrame extends JFrame {
private JButton btnStyle = new JButton("Bold");
private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

public TextStyleTestFrame() {
    super("TextPaneStyle Test");
    textPane.setText("Smaple String");
    this.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(btnStyle);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    btnStyle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            changeStyle();
        }
    });
}


private void changeStyle() {

    //get selected text style
    int start = textPane.getSelectionStart();
    int end = textPane.getSelectionEnd();

    if (start == end) {
        return;
    }
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();
    Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(start);
    AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
    //apply a new style based on previous 
    MutableAttributeSet asNew = new SimpleAttributeSet(as.copyAttributes());
    StyleConstants.setBold(asNew, !StyleConstants.isBold(as));
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, textPane.getSelectedText().length(), asNew, true);
    String text = (StyleConstants.isBold(as) ? "Cancel Bold" : "Bold");
    btnStyle.setText(text);
    boolean isBold = StyleConstants.isBold(as) ? false : true;
    boolean isItalic = StyleConstants.isItalic(as);
    System.out.println("selected value is isItalic?" + isItalic);
    System.out.println("selected value is isBold?" + isBold);
   }
```

Comment: THANKS DUDE, YOU ARE A LIFESAVER